# Root password option no longer appears on App Centre installs

Tags: release-hera, appcenter

Just recently when applying updates via AppCentre the option to enter the root password (or any passsword) no longer appears. I have no idea why but obviously I would like this protective feature back.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Then you must ask for this developers at git or Twitter. They are not using this forum. They have official channel on Facebook. Last time, about week ago they mentioned they are going to remove the password from the App Center. So eventually you can use terminal to install apps with

```
sudo apt install nameoftheapp
```